# EF Core always create .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1") on add-migration

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.2

I'm having a problem with Migration EF Core.

To make the scenario clear, I'm assigning it to an existing database, which is intended to use migration for database control from now on. But I am having difficulties.

What I have done so far.

1. I generated the scaffolding from the existing database.
2. I added the migration, so it generated all the "Up" for database creation.
3. In a clean database, ran update-database.

So far perfect, everything worked as expected. But from this step every time I generate a new migration he (the migration) insists on creating an Alter Column statement for all tables. For example:

```
  migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
            name: "rac_n_codigo",
            table: "tb_rac_raca",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(int),
            oldType: "int")
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1");
```

The creation table

```
  migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "tb_rac_raca",
            columns: table => new
            {
                rac_n_codigo = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                rac_c_nome = table.Column<string>(unicode: false, nullable: true),
                rac_d_alteracao = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "date", nullable: true),
                rac_c_usuario = table.Column<string>(unicode: false, nullable: true),
                rac_c_tipo = table.Column<string>(unicode: false, nullable: true),
                rac_d_modificacao = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime", nullable: true),
                rac_c_unique = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "(newid())"),
                rac_d_atualizado = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "(getdate())"),
                rac_d_inclusao = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "(getdate())")
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_tb_rac_raca", x => x.rac_n_codigo);
            });
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. Can you [submit a new issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/new/choose)?

Comment: I've got a very similar problem, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Core 3.0 or Core 3.1!

Add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational

Also, you might need to explicitly specify the identity column in the mapping.

```
builder.Property(o => o.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().UseIdentityColumn();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this sort of resolves, because it was not necessary to add or map, to use and test a solution and I need to update a reference "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" to 3.0.1, together with the installation "Relational" after this functioning perfectly, it started to generate migration only with consistent changes.

Comment: @FelipeAntunes Yes, I noticed that as well that it was sufficient to add Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational package.

Comment: I need some help, same problem but in EF Core 5. Click on linked question.

Answer (score 2):

I use **ValueGeneratedNever()**:

```
_ = builder.Property(x => x.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedNever();
```

EF Core 5+
In the metadata of the function description is:
**Configures a property to never have a value generated when an instance of this entity type is saved.**