# EF Core always create .Annotation(“SqlServer:Identity”, “1, 1”) on add-migration .NET 5 /.NET CORE 5

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5

> `<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>`

**Entity**

```cs
public class Country
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public string NationalityName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string PhonePrefix { get; set; } = null!;
    public string UnicodeFlag { get; set; } = null!;
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
```

**Configuration**

```
public class CountryConfiguration : EntityTypeConfigurationBase<Country>
{
    public CountryConfiguration(DatabaseFacade database) : base(database)
    {
    }

    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Country> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(e => e.Id);
        builder.Property(e => e.Name).IsUnicode().HasMaxLength(64);
        builder.Property(e => e.NationalityName).IsUnicode().HasMaxLength(64);
        builder.Property(e => e.PhonePrefix).HasMaxLength(20);
        builder.Property(e => e.UnicodeFlag).IsUnicode().HasMaxLength(4);
        builder.Property(e => e.Enabled);

        builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);
        builder.HasIndex(e => e.Name).IsUnique();
    }
}
```

**Context**

```cs
public class CoreDbContextBase : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; } = null!;

    public CoreDbContextBase(DbContextOptions options):base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CountryConfiguration(Database));           
    }
}
```

**DbContext Factory**

```
public class SqlServerDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<SqlServerDbContext>
{
    public SqlServerDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().
                SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddUserSecrets<SqlServerDbContext>()
                .AddJsonFile(EntitiesConstants.DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_FILE, false, true)
                .Build();
        DbSetting dbSetting = new DbSetting();
        configuration.Bind(nameof(DbSetting), dbSetting);

        DbContextOptions options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SqlServerDbContext>()
            .UseSqlServer(dbSetting.SqlServerConnectionString)
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true).Options;

        return new SqlServerDbContext(options);
    }
}
```

The above code or
Adding `modelBuilder.UseIdentityColumns();` or `modelBuilder.UseIdentityColumns(1, 1);` in OnModelCreating or adding `builder.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().UseIdentityColumn(1,1);` in configuration generates the following:

When add migration in my powershell script
`dotnet-ef migrations add "Migration_$($context)_$Guid" --startup-project "$StartupProject" --project "$Project" --context "$context" --output-dir "$outputDir" --verbose`

**1st migration** is created without any problem. ✔️

```
public partial class Migration_SqlServerDbContext_b3e04304812f4d33ae7355317f325f44 : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.EnsureSchema(
            name: "Base");

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Country",
            schema: "Base",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<long>(type: "bigint", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(500)", maxLength: 500, nullable: false),
                NationalityName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(500)", maxLength: 500, nullable: false),
                PhonePrefix = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(4)", maxLength: 4, nullable: false),
                UnicodeFlag = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(4)", maxLength: 4, nullable: false),
                Enabled = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("P_Country_Id", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "U_Country_Name",
            schema: "Base",
            table: "Country",
            column: "Name",
            unique: true);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Country",
            schema: "Base");
    }
}
```

**2nd,3rd,4th..Nth migrations with any changes in my model** creates the following ❌

```cs
public partial class Migration_SqlServerDbContext_e07c05fcf33d40d7a1754255a7364121 : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<long>(
            name: "Id",
            schema: "Base",
            table: "Country",
            type: "bigint",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(long),
            oldType: "bigint")
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<long>(
            name: "Id",
            schema: "Base",
            table: "Country",
            type: "bigint",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(long),
            oldType: "bigint")
            .OldAnnotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1");
    }
}
```

**I tried this** [EF Core always create .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59673398/ef-core-always-create-annotationsqlserveridentity-1-1-on-add-migration). But no result.

**Try adding** `modelBuilder.UseIdentityColumns(2, 1);` in OnModelCreating generates 1st migration with identity 1,1(bug?❌).

```
public partial class Migration_SqlServerDbContext_d5b7e1cf20914bf4acb8068c2c58c5be : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.EnsureSchema(
            name: "Base");

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Country",
            schema: "Base",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<long>(type: "bigint", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"), //BUG?
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(500)", maxLength: 500, nullable: false),
                NationalityName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(500)", maxLength: 500, nullable: false),
                PhonePrefix = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(4)", maxLength: 4, nullable: false),
                UnicodeFlag = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(4)", maxLength: 4, nullable: false),
                Enabled = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("P_Country_Id", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "U_Country_Name",
            schema: "Base",
            table: "Country",
            column: "Name",
            unique: true);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Country",
            schema: "Base");
    }
}
```

**Try adding** `builder.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().UseIdentityColumn(2,1);` resolves the problem the 1st migration is identity 2, 1. ✔️

```
public partial class Migration_SqlServerDbContext_c4823ca5280b4dda88c175f4e8a1a082 : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.EnsureSchema(
            name: "Base");

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Country",
            schema: "Base",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<long>(type: "bigint", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "2, 1"), //OK
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(500)", maxLength: 500, nullable: false),
                NationalityName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(500)", maxLength: 500, nullable: false),
                PhonePrefix = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(4)", maxLength: 4, nullable: false),
                UnicodeFlag = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(4)", maxLength: 4, nullable: false),
                Enabled = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("P_Country_Id", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "U_Country_Name",
            schema: "Base",
            table: "Country",
            column: "Name",
            unique: true);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Country",
            schema: "Base");
    }
}
```

**2nd,3rd,4th.... migrations** are generated with empty actions in both cases. ✔️

```cs
public partial class Migration_SqlServerDbContext_e07c05fcf33d40d7a1754255a7364455 : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

**References Project**

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="5.0.0-alpha.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

**References StartupProject**

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.1">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

My question is is there any way to solve these without having to initialize the identity field to 2?

Using the same context, configuration and entity in PostgreSql and MySql the migrations are generated correctly.

Comment: Having a similar issue, efcore 5.0 always generates the code to alter the identity column and the fails at runtime, did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: builder.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().UseIdentityColumn(2,1);   Starting identity from 2.

Comment: I am having the same problem...